# Process for reporting text display bug

Tags: discussion

The past couple of days I've been experiencing bugs in how the workplace displays.  These have been especially bad when trying to edit or vote for closure.  I've tried to attach a screen shot but am also unable to get that feature to work.

What is the process for reporting a bug?

Comment: Is it only on Workplace? Or everywhere on Stack Exchange? What Lilienthal put is probably the best bet, but a discussion here can be helpful too as there are sometimes site specific bugs too.

Comment: Everywhere on SE.  I'm not able to attach images and the reproduction step is "Hit Edit" or "Hit Close" and things look weird.

Comment: And there is my solution.  A corpoarte update yesterday downgraded my browser to an unsupported version.

Answer (score 2):

**You create a new question on meta and tag it with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag.**

Accordingly I've changed the tag on this question as it *isn't* a bug report. Please resubmit your bug with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag and include steps on how to reproduce etc.

**If the bug is not specific to this site or its meta, it should be reported on the [main StackExchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)**. Very few, if any, actual bugs should be specific to a single site.

Further reading:

- [How do I report a bug related to Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188266/how-do-i-report-a-bug-related-to-stack-exchange)
- [How does one report a bug in Stack Overflow HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111070/how-does-one-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow-html)
- [How can I report a bug in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285740/how-can-i-report-a-bug-in-stack-overflow)

**Security issues** should not be posted publicly but reported to the network administrators directly from the [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).